# Get iPads direction (N, E, S, W)

Tags: ios, objective-c, direction

Is it possible to get the current iPads direction like North, East, South, or West for example by CLLocationManager?

Comment: Yes, it's right there in the documentation for `CLLocationManager`. Look at `CLHeading`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for rotating pin in which direction its move
so might be it will helpful for you and by pin angle you will get ipad direction.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    // Use the true heading if it is valid. 
    CLLocationDirection direction = newHeading.magneticHeading;
    CGFloat radians = -direction / 180.0 * M_PI;

    self.strAccuracy = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1fmi",newHeading.headingAccuracy];    
    [lblAccuracy setText:self.strAccuracy];

    //Rotate Bearing View
    [self rotateBearingView:bearingView radians:radians];

    //For Rotate Niddle
    CGFloat angle = RadiansToDegrees(radians);  
    [self setLatLonForDistanceAndAngle];
    [self rotateArrowView:arrowView degrees:(angle + fltAngle)];
}

-(void)rotateArrowView:(UIView *)view degrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(degrees));
    view.transform = transform;
}

-(void)setLatLonForDistanceAndAngle
{
    dblLat1 = DegreesToRadians(appDelegate.dblLatitude);
    dblLon1 = DegreesToRadians(appDelegate.dblLongitude);

    dblLat2 = DegreesToRadians(objClsProductSearch.dblLatitude);
    dblLon2 = DegreesToRadians(objClsProductSearch.dblLongitude);

    fltLat = dblLat2 - dblLat1;
    fltLon = dblLon2 - dblLon1;
}

-(float)getAngleFromLatLon
{
    //Calculate angle between two points taken from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts    /latlong.html
    double y = sin(fltLon) * cos(dblLat2);
    double x = cos(dblLat1) * sin(dblLat2) - sin(dblLat1) * cos(dblLat2) * cos(dblLon2);
    CGFloat angle = RadiansToDegrees(atan2(y, x));
    return angle;
}
```